# Unify client ids from different Spreadsheet calling Google Cloud Endpoint through UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-endpoints

I have this scenario:

- A backend serving data using Google Cloud Endpoints based on Google App Engine Standard application
- An App Script project library which is working as "core" for the main script, where all the logic is built
- A bounded script inside a Google Spreadsheet which simply calls the library for processing, providing values from sheet

The data retrieved from the sheet are sent to the Google Cloud Endpoints (for processing) using `UrlFetchApp`

```
var url = ... // url of Google Cloud Endpoints;
var options = {
  'headers': { 
    "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
  }
};
var fetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

The Endpoint is under OAuth authentication, so the clientId of the calling script (which is automatically generated, as long as the cloud project, when an AppsScript is created) need to be whitelisted.

Each different user need to have his own spreadsheet, I'm now creating a copy of the Spreadsheet and I'm sharing it to each single user. In this way the bounded script is copied as well and the main processing code remains in the "core" project which is imported as library in the bound script.

The problem is here: every time I duplicate the Spreadsheet, a new clientId is generated and so I need to whitelist every single value in the Cloud Endnpoints value.

Because this kind of logic is unsustainable (I have about 100 users), I'm looking a way to perform the http connections using the clientId of the library (which is shared among all the Spreadsheets) so the backend configuration is limited to only a single value.

Is this configuration viable?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain for the Apps Script side, as an Endpoints engineer, so I will present Endpoints-side solutions, of which I can think of two.

1. In your servlet init parameters, set `clientIdWhitelistEnabled` to `false` to let any client ID use Endpoints.
2. If you would like a dynamic whitelisting solution, you can write your own `com.google.api.server.spi.config.Authenticator` class which checks the client ID off of a database, rather than hardcoded annotation.